# Can anyone identify this spider for me?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

There is a spider on the window of my office that I've been trying to identify for the past few days but can't quite figure it out. My coworker thinks it's a Furrow Orb Weaver but I'm not sure. My office is located near Raleigh, NC and unfortunately I'm on the third floor and the spider always faces away from me, so these are the best pictures that I could get.

[[image: 1]]

[image]